# Do normal navigation in a Modal page seems to be not supported [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation

I have tried to use normal navigation inside a Modal page but when I do navigate an error is displayed:

```
PushAsync is not supported on Android, please use NavigationPage
```

I am using `NavigationPage()` in my modal page to allow me to navigate in a normal way,
is it possible?

code:

code for navigating to the Modal Page:

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(
                    new NavigationPage(new MyModalPage());
```

(In modal page)
Code for navigating from the modal page to MySecondPage with normal navigation:

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(
                    new NavigationPage(new MySecondPage()));
```

then popus the error mentioned

Comment: you need to post the relevant code if you want us to help you

Comment: @Jason I don’t want anyone to solve for me a code, I just want an explanation about if Xamarin forms is allowed to do what I want

Comment: Yes, you can do navigation within a modal.  But the error you're getting makes me think that you have a problem in your code.

Comment: @Jason I have edited my post, can you refer to it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your modal page, don't do this

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(
                new NavigationPage(new MySecondPage()));
```

instead do this

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MySecondPage());
```